# How to solve this problem with my subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, url, links, subdomain

I have my site hosted at http://blog.rgksugan.in. 
I have set a subdomain in it for my blog.
But after landing on my blog whatever other links I click i get the link as
http://rgksugan.in/blog/wordpress/stack-overflow/.

I want it to be http://blog.rgksugan.in/stack-overflow

What should I do...?

Comment: You should ask it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ I don't remember coz' I hate wasting time doing insatallation chores with WP. Anyway I'm quite sure your subdomin document folder is http://rgksugan.in/blog/ so it's simply WP creating wrong links. It should be easy to fix it's probably just a matter of setting something in WP configuration.

Comment: Did aendrew answer your question rgksugan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally can do this in wp-admin by going to Settings -> General and setting "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" to include the subdomain. That said, please read this before do that: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Be forewarned this may break content and it seems going to blog.rgksugan.in just redirects to the main site without forwarding any of the requests:
http://blog.rgksugan.in/blog/2011/01/27/capture-network-packets-java/ and
http://blog.rgksugan.in/2011/01/27/capture-network-packets-java/
both redirect to your front page. This makes me think WP isn't actually installed at blog.rgksugan.in and that the subdomain is just a forwarding DNS record.

Basically, make sure the site is *actually* hosted at blog.rgjsugan.in before trying to change anything in WP Settings.